# Close keepalive socket on FIN packet - SocketAsyncEventArgs server

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, server, tcp

I have a C# SocketAsyncEventArgs server implementation that only sends packets to a client in response to an incoming message from the client.

Process as seen by WireShark packet inspection:

1. Client establishes a TCP keepalive socket connection with the server [SYN]
2. Server accepts connection [SYN, ACK]
3. Client acks connection accept [ACK]
4. Client sends data to server [PSH, ACK]
5. Server ACKs data receive [ACK]
6. Server sends data response [PSH, ACK]
7. Client ACKs data receive [ACK]
   Step 4-7 occurs n times
8. Client closes socket, sends Fin to server [FIN, ACK]
9. Server ACKs FIN [ACK]

Meanwhile, amongst all this, the server is sending the client keepalive packets and the client responds to them. Even after the socket is closed and the client application is terminated, the client is still responding to [TCP KEEP-ALIVE] with [TCP KEEP-ALIVE ACK] so the server never auto-terminates the socket on the server side.

Can i get the server to act upon the [FIN, ACK] packet somehow and close the socket?

My server implementation is almost verbatim the example as specified [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs?view=net-5.00).

The general wisdom around the net on how keepalive client disconnects should be handled is when sending to a client, a server should be able to gracefully detect an unsuccessful send and terminate the socket accordingly.
Though, seeing as the server only sends as response to a received message, the server will never send when the client is disconnected.

I really would prefer to disconnect on receipt of the [Fin, ACK], rather than taking a connection polling approach.

Also does anyone know why the client endpoint is ACKing the [TCP KEEP-ALIVE] packet after the client application shutdowns and closes the socket and terminates the application?

Comment: Sending further keep alive packets after the connection is closed sounds strange for me. Are you sure that you are correctly interpreting the packet capture. Could you provide the capture (in full as pcap, i.e. not just an image of Wireshark).

Comment: Yeah ill say... however ive canned the approach and gone with another implementation route and it seems to be working now.